# Returning the maximum ROW_NUMBER for each of the group

Tags: sql

My data looks like this

```
TYPE   Unique_no 
ABC     1
ABC     2
XYZ     3
PQR     4
XYZ     5
ABC     6
```

I have used row_number() for Partitioning the data, but how can I get maximum row_count of each group?
Any help please.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking...are you asking how to get the max `Unique_no` grouped by `Type` ?

Comment: You are expect the count for the `Type` or maximum value for the `Type`? The wordings are confusing, can you add the expected result?

Comment: Edit your question and provide desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one and check

```
Select TYPE,MAX(Unique_no) from <yourtablename> group by TYPE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use COUNT():

```
SELECT Type, COUNT(*) as MAXROWNUM FROM T GROUP BY Type
```